# How should I overcome from this hibernate error of java Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode

Tags: java, hibernate

Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)

Answer (score 0):

In you spring context part, set the following.

```
<!--default is required transaction-->
<tx:method name="*"/>
```

I think your current is set as :

```
<tx:method name="*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED" />
```

Also you can set @Transactional(readOnly = false) to ur class method (let's say DAO Class methods like persist, update or delete) which need to write in database.

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void UpdateEmployee() {
      ...
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know where should I put this line <!--default is required transaction-->
<tx:method name="*"/> in below configuration file :

Comment: add @Transactional above your function. Check my edit section